# Convert Mahlkönig EK43 settings to other grinders

Tags: aeropress

I wanted to test the new AeroPress World Champions recipe, and my question is how do I translate the setting "7.3" on Mahlkönig EK43 to my Graef CM 80.

Is there any way to get the same result on my grinder?

Comment: You mean [model EK 43](http://www.mahlkoenig.de/file/download/default/id/3786), right? I can't find a model EK 34. If you're looking at [this AeroPress page](http://worldaeropresschampionship.com/recipes/) I think one has a typo. I think a good way to approach this would be to understand the average particle size created by the various settings on EK 43. I have this very same question and haven't found a source for it yet...

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it. Maybe there is a local barista that has one and lets you compare.

Comment: Yannick, isn't it better to form a question sentence as title? "How to convert Mahlkönig EK43 grinder settings to Graef CM 80 settings?" or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question as well. The Mahklonig scale is from 1 (fine) - 11 (coarse), based on some images, so you could assume that 7.3 is about a drip grind, and then adjust to taste based on results

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just apply a formula based on how many notches a machine has.  This would assume that all machines start and stop at the same point ie if one goes to 10 and one goes to 12 then the formula assumes 10 & 12 are the same grind which is not the case.  I believe the EK43 does an extreme 'Turkish' grind which many machines do not so that may throw the calculations out.

Answer (score 0):

On the Graef CM 80 grinder manual, it looks looks it has 12 notches on the setting wheel. How ever many, it's a straightforward algebra equation where you solve for X. --Substitute the actual number of notches on the setting ring for 12, if 12 is incorrect. Assuming it's 12, then...

11 over 12 equals 7.3 over X. (12x7.3)/11=X  X=7.96 (or rounding up, 8).

I find it hard to believe that the grind is so course.