# EK43 settings for shop grinding

Tags: grinder, coffee-shop

I was wondering if anyone has a list of EK43 grind settings for different brew methods that they use for pre grinding coffee bags for customers.

I know that pre grinding can be complicated for all sorts of reasons (different brew methods/preferences etc.) but figure customers who are ok with pre ground are also ok with not getting perfect extractions.

If no one has already done the hard work, I'll post what I end up with after playing around with different settings for different brew methods.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Matt

Comment: This is most likely opinion-based and there is no definitive answer for this. I'd suggest heading to your local roaster or coffee shop (or online) that sells pre-ground, buy some bags for different brew methods and use those grind sizes as a reference to match your EK43 settings. Or, like you said, find the settings that work for you and use that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think absolute settings are difficult to say on this grinder, due to the fact that the burr position is adjustable separately from the grind adjustment knob. The [product page](http://www.mahlkoenig.com/en_products/EK-EKK-43.html) and linked manual don't have any indication other than relative size. There are discussions at [Home Barista](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1747/) and [previously here](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1747/). As an aside, I think it's delightful that the grind settings go from one [up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven).

Comment: Despite some evidence to the contrary, let's leave this open for now to see if anyone has some good guidelines when adjusted according to the recommendations in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

**Note** All information below is entirely based on my adjustment to make 11 be a french press / cupping grind thus normalizing the rest of the settings.  How I came up with the adjustment was because at the time I had my home grinder configured for french press and was using it daily, and I simply did a comparison of grind levels until the adjustment appeared to be the same size.  Given a normalized 11 setting, everything else should match up.

When I first purchased my EK43, I felt that it did not allow coarse enough grinding to get to French press level grinds.  I pulled the tap screws on the grind adjustment knob and and loosened the burrs equivalent of 2 grind units (effectively making grind level 3 originally a 1).  This adjusted the grinder such that an 11 was a French press grind.

Once this is configured, and presuming you are using the 'new' EK43 burrs, I use the following settings:

11 - French Press and cupping samples

7.5-8 - Drip brew and Keurig depending on desired strength.  This setting will also work with Bunn brewers IF the user uses the proper amount of grounds, which almost no one does.. For 110oz airpots we were using 175g grounds at a 7.5.

4.5 - For those stubborn people who use half as many grounds as they are supposed to on Bunn brewers..  I've got a few companies like this, and have to grind fine, otherwise the coffee comes out underextracted.  I wish I could just tell them to double the amount of coffee they put in the machine but.. oh well.

This setup is basically useless for espresso grinding.  It works halfway decent if you are using a pressurized portafilter (like an EC155 or something) If someone asked for an espresso level grind on this setup, I would give them a 1 and it would be quite fine, but probably wouldn't be clumping at all. No one discerning enough to know the differences in espresso grinds is going to ask for it pre-ground anyways so I just ignore this bit.

All of these settings are with basically brand new burrs.. of course as they wear, I will have to adjust accordingly.